# Why Google Analytics Code Making Request to doubleclick.net?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have integrated Google Analytics service to my javascript app like below:

```
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', {
  trackingId: '...',
  cookieDomain: 'auto',
  name: '...',
  clientId: '...'
});
ga('tracker.require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('tracker.require', 'linkid');
```

While i am using the app sometimes i detect a network request that tries to load image from `https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect?...`

I am not sure what this is about as i integrated only google analytics library to my app.

1. What is it? Is it related to Data Sharing Settings in Google Analytics Account?
2. Why is this happening sometimes? Can i control it?

Answer (score 1):

You may have enabled [advertising features](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=en) in your Google Analytics account